# Django admin customization without changing the default templates

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have one admin page. Where I want to add some link such that on click on that link pop up should be visible where we can set some value and alert something. I Don't want to post something in back end. So How we can achieve this without downloading change_list.html and change_form.html from default django site packages.?

Answer (score 0):

You can [override admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). As the docs state, you override the block you are interested modifying the contents of that block, by placing it in a file in a certain directory, and naming it after what type of page you want to change.

It's all explained in the docs.